# PowerShell rename files

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a database full of .pdf and .dwf files.
I need to rename these.

The files are named as follows:

```
123456 text text.pdf
```

And should look like this:

```
123456000_text_text.text.pdf
```

I can replace the spaces with the following command:

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.name -replace " ","_"}
```

Now I need a command to insert "0" three times after the first 6 digits.

Can someone help me?

Thanks already

Comment: What have you tried so far to add the zeros? Are the digit always 6 and you want a 9 digit number? What if it was 12345, should it be 12345000 or 123450000?

Comment: Its always 6 and i need 9

Comment: I am just thinking or trying if I can split the name like a string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to filter on *.pdf and *.dwf files only and also if the filenames match the criterion of starting with 6 digits followed by a space character. Then you can use regex replacements like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Test -File | Where-Object { $_.Name -match '^\d{6} .*\.(dwf|pdf)$' } | 
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '^(\d{6}) ', '${1}000_' -replace '\s+', '_'}
```

**Before:**

```
D:\TEST
    123456 text text.dwf
    123456 text text.pdf
    123456 text text.txt
```

**After:**

```
D:\TEST
    123456 text text.txt
    123456000_text_text.dwf
    123456000_text_text.pdf
```

**Regex details of filename -match:**

```
^               Assert position at the beginning of the string
\d              Match a single digit 0..9
   {6}          Exactly 6 times
\               Match the character “ ” literally
.               Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *            Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\.              Match the character “.” literally
(               Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
                Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
      dwf       Match the characters “dwf” literally
   |            Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
      pdf       Match the characters “pdf” literally
)              
$               Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Comment: Add `$_.FullName` instead of just `$_.Name`.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala Nope, I'm piping the FileInfo object.

Comment: You just edit it!?! lol could've sworn i didn't see it, my mistake(:

Answer (score 3):

What you have is `123456 text text.pdf`
Want it to look like `123456000_text_text.pdf`
A systematic way to achieve this would be>>

```
$const = "123456 text text.pdf"
$filename = $const -replace " ","_"
$temp = $filename.split("_")[0]
$rep1 = ([string]$temp).PadRight(9,'0')
$output =  $filename -replace $temp,$rep1 

Write-Host $output -ForegroundColor Green
```

[image]

The great thing about this method is that it will always trail with 0s keeping your number string to 9 digits.